# hummus module causing npm install to fail

Tags: node.js, npm

I've tried to run my node project on my windows,
but when I want to use the command:

```
npm install  or  npm update
```

it shows the errors below

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have already removed node and reinstalled it, but there is still the same issue.

```
os: windows 10
node version: 8.8.1
npm version: 5.4.2
```

my package.json file

```
{
"name": "mytasklist",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Simple task manager",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node server.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"binary": "^0.3.0",
"body-parser": "^1.17.2",
"dataformat": "^1.0.0",
"dateformat": "^2.0.0",
"ejs": "^2.5.7",
"express": "^4.15.4",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"fs-extra": "^4.0.2",
"html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
"hummus": "^1.0.83",
"js-base64": "^2.3.2",
"js-sha256": "^0.6.0",
"mocha": "^4.0.1",
"mongojs": "^2.4.0",
"mssql": "^4.1.0",
"multer": "^1.3.0",
"node-base64-image": "^1.0.4",
"node-pdftk": "^1.1.1",
"pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
"pdftohtmljs": "^0.4.2",
"phantom-html-to-pdf": "^0.5.5",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"request": "^2.81.0",
"requests": "^0.2.2",
"sha256": "^0.2.0",
"soap": "^0.21.0",
"tedious": "^2.0.0",
"winston": "^2.3.1",
"winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.4.6"
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show please, your `package.json` file?

Comment: I've edit my post.

Comment: Let me ask you to move the `package.json` in another folder outside your project. And after run again `npm install` in the root of your project and show the output here.

Comment: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Money\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Money\package.json'

Comment: It seems that the error is coming from one of your dependencies in `package.json`. Can you proceed with `npm init` and reinstall your module one after another?

Comment: and if I type in the same command `npm install --save hummus`  it outputs the same error above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157535/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-lee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error does not seem to come from `npm` but from your dependencies. So you can try the following.

The error seems to come from the dependency: `hummus`. The error message indicates that you need to have `python` in your system. You can consider installing python and then after retry to install the `hummus` module. The following [link](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/issues/162) can also give a hint. If it does not work, you might consider restarting from the scratch.

**Restart from the scratch**

Remove your `package.json` file. Initialize your project `npm init` and reinstall your dependencies one after another. Then, you will be able to identify which dependency is causing your install to fail.